# batch script logs in file as well as on screen

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to print batch script logs on screen as well as writing it into log file. Using following program I can write it into file but this is not displaying anything on screen.

```
if not exist logs mkdir logs
if not "%1"=="STDOUT_TO_FILE"  %0 STDOUT_TO_FILE %* >logs\execution_%SUBFILENAME%.log 2>&1
shift /1
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I already tried several ways from the answers posted here or from different questions, some how non of them is working as i want !

Comment: Where does the log originate from? are you reading from file, or command that issues it?

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard -  command that issues it and a Java application that I am calling using this batch file!

Comment: use a for loop. `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('java program') do (echo %%a & echo %%a >outfile.txt >2&1)`